# Tengo el mismo código en dos aplicaciones diferentes, pero en una tengo este error: this OperationContextScope being disposed out of order

Tags: c#, asp.net

Después de leer documentación y foros, vi que el problema se genera porque estoy usando un await dentro de OperationContextScope. Estoy usando **`ASP.NET Core 6 MVC y C#.`**

El problema es que el código está replicado en dos aplicaciones diferentes, literalmente tienen el mismo código, pero en una tengo el error OperationContextScope y en la otra no.

Usé puntos de interrupción pero se rompe después cuando sale del `using (new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))`

Perdon si me equivoco en algo que puede ser novato, pero me parece muy raro que en una aplicación funcione perfectamente y en la otra no, y las dos son EXACTAMENTE iguales.

```
  [HttpPost]
     public async Task<ActionResult> ConexionWSAsync(string cuit, string pedidocliente, string dirmail, string acepta)
            {
                try
                {
                    SoapClient client = new SoapClient(binding, endpoint);
                    ZWsGetList zWsGetList = new ZWsGetList();
    
                    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = _userName;
                    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = _password;
    
                    using (new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
                    {
                        SoapAuthenticationHeader.Create(client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName, client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password);

                        zWsGetList = CreateGetListObject(cuit);
    
                        var zWsResponse1 = await client.ZWsGetListAsync(zWsGetList);
                    }
                }         
            }


public class SoapAuthenticationHeader
{
    public SoapAuthenticationHeader() { }

    public static void Create(string username, string password)
    {
        string auth = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));

        HttpRequestMessageProperty requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
        requestMessage.Headers.Add("Authorization", auth);
        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = requestMessage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instale algunos paquetes NuGet  y termino funcionando:

```
System.ComponentModel.Annotations
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
System.ServiceModel.Duplex
System.ServiceModel.Federation
System.ServiceModel.Http
System.ServiceModel.NetTcp
System.ServiceModel.Security
```

Algunos vienen por default y otros los instale manualmente, pero esos son los que tengo y logré que funcionara. Espero que lo encuentren útil.